# How to populate Publication and components in an aspx page

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I created a Button on the ribbon "SelectCp".

OnClick of the button I am launching a custom aspx page.

Custom aspx page is having a dropdown with the items like.

1. Select CP
2. Etc

Now, when user will select the option "Select CP", I need to populate all the publication in a listitem on the aspx page. When user will select a publication, I need to populate all the component in another list.

Can anyone give an idea how to proceed?

**ADDED**

I am proceeding Like this, but its not giving the list of publication in the listbox on the aspx page.

```
protected void ddSelectOption_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //CommonTridionTools objCmnUnPub = new CommonTridionTools();
        CoreServiceSession client = new CoreServiceSession();
        SessionAwareCoreServiceClient csClient = client.GetClient();
        ReadOptions readoption = new ReadOptions();
        List<string> PublicationList = new List<string>();
        List<string> ComponentList = new List<string>();

        if (ddSelectOption.SelectedItem.Equals("Select CP"))
        {
            FolderData RootFolder =(FolderData)csClient.Read(tridionPageId, readoption);
            var filter = new OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData
            {
                Recursive = true,
                ItemTypes = new ItemType[] { ItemType.Publication,ItemType.Component, ItemType.ComponentTemplate },
            };
            XElement CompList = csClient.GetListXml(RootFolder.Id,filter);

            foreach (var comp in CompList.Elements())
            {
                PublicationData Publication =(PublicationData)csClient.Read(comp.Attribute("ID").Value, readoption);
                var MetadataXML = new XmlDocument();
                MetadataXML.LoadXml(Publication.Metadata);
                PublicationList.Add(Publication.Id)
                lbPublication.DataSource = PublicationList;

            }
        }
```

Comment: There are literally dozens of examples all over the place of people interacting with Tridion and writing GUI extensions. Did you try those? Where did you get stuck? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have examples for such a Publication drop-down and other controls on the [PowerTools 2011 open source project](http://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/). See the **Example Extension** source for:

- [markup](http://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/source/browse/trunk/PowerTools.Editor/PowerTools/Client/Example/Example.aspx)
- [script](http://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/source/browse/trunk/PowerTools.Editor/PowerTools/Client/Example/Example.js)
- [service code](http://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/source/browse/trunk/PowerTools.Model/Services/Example.svc.cs)

Start by reviewing these, then share your code or start another question when you're ready.

Note the nice [volunteers for the project](http://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/wiki/Volunteers) created a [base class](http://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/wiki/BaseClass) that does some of the work.

Comment: Thanks Alvin, i will go through these, and once done i will share my codes.

Answer (score 2):

A great example of allowing the user to select items, can be found in the [Item Selector extension](https://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/itemselector.aspx).

It has most of the parts that you are asking for, although not necessarily in a copy/paste format. Study it and reach out to us if you get stuck modifying it to your needs or if a certain part is not clear.

Comment: yes sure frank, i will use the concept shown there, and will come up with a solution .

Answer (score 1):

This Item Selector Extension is nice of course, but since the amount of Publications doesn't change very often you could also consider retrieving the data for this list from a configuration file.

This way you can also much easier filter this list with only the appropriate Publications, not just the ones a user has access to.

Comment: Thanks arjen . Please have a look how i am proceeding, but using this i am not able to get list of publication in the listbox on the aspx page. Kindly make me correct if i am wrong direction.

Comment: You're trying to get a Publication using the Component ID.

Comment: :I was committing few mistakes there in my code. Now i corrected that and i am getting now component and component template in two different lists on selecting a Publication.